# сборка плагина для Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Достался "в наследство" проект, в котором есть инструментарий на Qt в частности плагин для импорта SWF во внутренний редактор.
Был написан во времена старого Qt Creator, я обновил объявление плагина, вроде бы ругань на это прошла, плагин компилирует, а вот дальше непонятное нечто.
в процессе линовки выдает

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/rtn/Downloads/qt-creator-master/build/bin/Qt
>   Creator.app/Contents/Frameworks
>
> ld: library not found for -lCore
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что плагины креатора не собраны как библиотеки и не находятся линковщиком. Поиск по папкам не дал результата, ничего похожего я не нашел. Как их собрать тоже не пойму

Собираю под макосью в Qt Creator 3.5.1

Comment: А этот путь до Вашего креатора?(`/Users/rtn/Downloads/qt-creator-master/build/bin/Qt Creator.app/Contents/Frameworks`)

Comment: по пути `/Users/rtn/Downloads/qt-creator-master/` лежат исходники qt creator которые мне понадобились, чтобы проект начал собираться, сам креатор я качал с сайта в виде dmg образа и ставил как обычное приложение

**UPD:** попробовал создать новый проект та же проблема - нет библиотек для линковки. Возможно мне нужна была другая версия креатора?

Comment: Это должен быть путь до самого креатора, а не до исходников, насколько я понимаю. А вообще, читайте мануал по сборке плагина для креатора, там всё должно быть.

Comment: и да и нет. Этот путь строится из переменной QTCREATOR_SOURCES, но при этом рядом с ними ищется собранный в пакет креатор, который нужно строить самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему переборкой QtCreator из исходников, но [по более свежему мануалу](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Creator_from_Git). В результате чего у меня получился пакет с нужными либами и исходниками в одном каталоге, что позволяет стоить плагины в релизе, если вы хотите их отлаживать, нужно построить креатор с включенной отладкой, чтобы были либы с постфиксом d в имени.